# how to prevent textwidth from reseting on txt files

Tags: vim

Whenever I open txt files (and some others) I get my textwidth set to 80. I think this is coming from syntax or ftplugin. I'd like to fix this in my _vimrc so I don't have to call "set tw=0" every time I open a file that has this setting.

Comment: While a perfectly good question, StackOverflow.com is for programming questions. I'd suggest that yours is better posted on SuperUser.com (also part of the StackExchange network).

Comment: @CharlesBurns - SO is also for "software development tools" which unlike some other editors maybe, Vim and Emacs have always been part of.

Comment: Hmm... then it would seem that the majority of 12538 items tagged vim should be in superuser? Unless they are about programming vim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was in `vimrc_example.vim` the line

`autocmd FileType text setlocal textwidth=78`

sets the textwidth on txt files. Also my `formatoptions` get reset and no longer have `l` or `lv` (`verbose` doesn't give any detail who did it)

Comment: If `:verbose set option?` does not say where the option was set, then either you are just getting the default (the option was never set) or you changed it interactively.  Possibly, vim can be fooled by something like `:execute "set option=value"` in a script.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that you are getting the defaults, not a setting from an ftplugin.  Check

```
:verbose set tw? ft?
```

to confirm.  See the examples under

```
:help autocmd-patterns
```

for one way to set your own defaults for *.txt files.

On second thought, the default for `'tw'` is zero, so you are not getting defaults.  Perhaps some ftplugin used `:set` instead of `:setlocal` and you are getting the global value of the option.  I think the rest of what I wrote is still on target.

Comment: Nice! That gives me some visibility.

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/vimrc` can also contain a `set tw` command - it certainly did in my case, thereby forcing all my files to a text width of 78 until I changed it manually.